# Objective C: Is there a difference between these two statements?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, syntax

**Setup**:

```
@interface Base : NSObject {}
@end

@interface Subclass : Base {}
@end

…

Subclass* sub = …;
```

Is there a difference between:

```
// No explicit cast.
Base* base = sub;
```

and:

```
// Explicit cast, but does this actually DO anything different at runtime?
Base* base = (Base*) sub;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treating a subclass like its parent class is quite common and safe. (Unless you’re misusing inheritance in your design.) The cast does nothing extra in runtime and is not needed during compilation; it’s completely useless as far as the machine is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You *will* get a compiler warning about `ClassSuper* super = base;` since not every `ClassBase` instance is `ClassSuper` instance. So if you really know what you do you should make explicit cast to stop compiler from whining.

Comment: It would be wiser to check `isKindOfClass:` instead of casting without verification.

Comment: That's why I said 'if you really know what you do'. Context of this cast is technically irrelevant but I admit that from pedagogic point of view you are right :).

Comment: Base class and superclass are synonymous -- what the heck are you demonstrating, an upcast or a downcast?

Comment: Don't get mad. They are class names used in OP question. Both name _and_ semantics have been edited by OP & zoul after I answered - see first revision http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5261256/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Hmmh
Warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct AbstractClass *', expected 'struct ConcreteClass *'

Comment: Yes, I got the super and the base muddled my bad.. ill edit now

Answer (score -1):

Your casted statement is only valid if `base` really points to an `instance of ClassSuper`. Since `ClassBase` includes more types then `ClassSuper` your cast **might fail during runtime**!

Your first statement though won't fail because Objective-C doesn't really care about the type during assignment. So your `ClassSuper* super` is more an `id super` during runtime. The cast though will be verified and throw errors if not fulfilled.

Comment: Ah! So you are saying there IS a diference at run time.  The cast is dynamically verified?

Comment: No. The cast is a compile-time construct, and no more. There is no run-time code generated from such a cast. It does not change the code that is generated at all.